# Modules how do I change a variable from the importing script?

Tags: javascript, module

Having a hard time finding an answer for this:

Let's say I'm using modules and on my first script I have a variable like this:

SCRIPT1

```
import * as SCRIPT2 from './script2.js';
var action = "stop";

SCRIPT2.changeAction();
```

And then on my SCRIPT2 I have something like this:

```
export function changeAction(){
//how do I change the variable on SCRIPT1 from stop to go?
action = "go";
}
```

Thank you! Any help for a newb is appreciated.

Comment: PS I don't want to do it this way: SCRIPT2.changeAction(action); One solution would be to pass the entire first script as an argument. Another would be to somehow reference Script1 from Script2 and just change the variable that way. I don't know how to do either.

Comment: In the example you post, I don't think it's possible cause your variable is defined in SCRIPT1 and you use SCRIPT2 in SCRIPT1. SCRIPT2 has no knowledge of the variable in SCRIPT1.

Comment: But come on, there has to be some way. This is just basic common sense as far as functionality goes.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? If the variable is defined in SCRIPT2, you can possibly change it in SCRIPT1. You may need to export it in SCRIPT2. Wy don't you use parameters though?

Answer (score 0):

You can return value from Script2 and  assign it  to action.

// script1.js

```
import * as SCRIPT2 from './script2.js';
var action = "stop";

action = SCRIPT2.changeAction();
```

// script2.js

```
export function changeAction(){
  action = "go";
  return action;
}
```